# Is Visual Studio Code compatible with Python64

Tags: python

Visual Studio Code comes only in 32 bit. But is it compatible with the latest Python3 64 bit?

I need to use Python64. Using Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Apparently many IDE's are 32 bit, but this does not stop them from interacting with 64 bit language packages.